# Jquery no errors but not working

Tags: jquery, callback

I want the element `<article>` to `fadeOut()` after my `<h2>` slides to the left, the slide works fine, but after that the article won't dissapear.

Jquery:
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '.sectiontitel', function(){ 
            $(this).addClass('off');

```
        $(this).find('span').animate({
            'margin-right': '350px',
        },200,

            function(){
                $(this).children('article').fadeOut(300);
            });

    });

    $(document).on('click', '.off', function(){ 
        $(this).removeClass('off');
        $(this).addClass('on');

        $(this).find('span').animate({
            'margin-right': '2px',
        },200);    });

    $(document).on('click', '.on', function(){ 
        $(this).removeClass('on');
        $(this).addClass('off');

        $(this).find('span').animate({
            'margin-right': '350px',
        },200);
    });
});
```

Jfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6x3ka0rq/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element arctice is not a descendant of `sectiontitel` use `closest` then `find` to get arcticle

```
$(this).closest('section').find('article').fadeOut(300);
```